# Can't connect on oracle unless DBA

Tags: oracle, authentication, ora-01722

I just created a new user, it DOES have create session, but everytime i try to connect on PLSQL Developer I get ORA-00604, ORA-01722 and ORA-06512

However, if i grant DBA access, i can log on with no problems.

Hints?
I don't have any connection trigger.

Comment: What's the full error message stack if you connect using SQL*Plus?

Comment: Do you mean it only happens on SQL Developer? What happens when you connect using SQL*Plus? Is there auditing enabled on the database? Are you sure there are no LOGON triggers?

Answer (score 1):

ORA-01722 is INVALID_NUMBER

Maybe PL/SQL developer is trying to execute something on connection.

If you are absolutely doubly sure that there isn't a connection trigger (and look for a database level one), then create one for that schema that enables a trace. Then look in the trace file for the 1722 error and see what statement it is trying to execute.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01722 indicates some code is hurling an INVALID_NUMBER exception.

Connect as a DBA and have a look in DBA_TRIGGERS.  Is there an AFTER LOGON trigger?  If so, look at the code in the trigger body.  Is there anything which is doing a TO_NUMBER() conversion; remember to consider implicit conversion (inserting a non-numeric value into a numeric column, etc).

Regular users are stymied by errors in LOGON triggers but DBAs get a free pass.  Otherwise, who would be able to connect to the database and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00604 : If you're running 11g check [this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00604_error_occurred_and_recursive_sql_level_string.htm).  There are apparently several issues with 11g that can cause ORA-00604 errors to pop up unexpectedly.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: That note refers to 11i of E-Business Suite not 11g of the database.